# onnxruntime not using CUDA

Tags: onnx, onnxruntime

Environment:

- CentOS 7
- python 3.9.5
- CUDA: 11.4
- cudnn: 8.2.4
- onnxruntime-gpu: 1.9.0
- nvidia driver: 470.82.01
- 1 tesla v100 gpu

while onnxruntime seems to be recognizing the gpu, when inferencesession is created, no longer does it seem to recognize the gpu. the following code shows this symptom.

```
import  onnxruntime as ort


print(f"onnxruntime device: {ort.get_device()}") # output: GPU

print(f'ort avail providers: {ort.get_available_providers()}') # output: ['CUDAExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider']

ort_session = ort.InferenceSession(onnx_file, providers=["CUDAExecutionProvider"])

print(ort_session.get_providers()) # output: ['CPUExecutionProvider']
```

I have no idea what could cause the inferencesession to not detect and use the CUDA gpu.

I have tried reinstalling `onnxruntime-gpu` after removing `onnxruntime` and `onnx` package, but this problem persists.

any suggestions on where to look at?

Answer (score 3):

after adding appropriate PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH the code works.
I guess I neglected to add them because I was so used to not caring about them  while using pytorch for a long time.

what I did:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.4/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

after this, the code in the question worked and the final line gave the output that I wanted.

```
print(ort_session.get_providers()) # output: ['CUDAExecutionProvider', 'CPUExecutionProvider']
```

and I can see gpu memory being consumed in `nvidia-smi`

Comment: I did this solution for my problem but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you ensure the version of your CUDA is correct? @mohsen_m

Comment: I am running through the same problem and I could not solve it

Comment: In case you think your CUDA install is solid; OP tried to reinstall `onnxruntime-gpu`, which didn't seem to work. However, for me `pip install onnxruntime-gpu` worked.

Comment: Make sure the requirements documented here are met: https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/execution-providers/CUDA-ExecutionProvider.html

You will need to install cuDNN and its dependencies (zlib) as well. https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html